# Stacked tikz reports style

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw stacked reports as in the image. However, I have been unable to do it all day. Any suggestions please? [image: enteenter image description herer image description here]

Comment: These are nodes with a `double copy shadow` page 783 in recent pgfmanual.

Comment: Thank you. Found it on page 699. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border={0pt 0pt 5pt 5pt}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\tikz[nodes={shape=tape, draw=green, tape bend top=none,
             tape bend height=.3ex, fill=white, double copy shadow}]
  \node foreach[count=\i] \t in {A, AB, CD} at (\i, 0) {\t};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]